# How to change directory through a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cd

I'm making a batch file (*.bat) for myself to try make some things easier file where I enter commands with adb.exe.
The problem is, any code after 'adb shell' is not executed in the batch.
So if I had a batch with the following:

```
adb shell
cd /storage/emulated/legacy/
mkdir $(date +%d-%m-%Y)_OniFiles
mv *.oni $(date +%d-%m-%Y)_OniFiles
adb pull /storage/emulated/legacy/$(date +%d-%m-%Y)_OniFiles C:/$(date +%d-%m-%Y)_OniFiles
```

'cd /storage/emulated/legacy/

mkdir $(date +%d-%m-%Y)_OniFiles

mv *.oni $(date +%d-%m-%Y)_OniFiles

adb pull /storage/emulated/legacy/$(date +%d-%m-%Y)_OniFiles C:/$(date +%d-%m-%Y)_OniFiles'

will not be executed and stays at '$'.
It seems like it's too deep for a batch file to enter codes.
I also tried pushing a sh with the same script and run it from adb but then all I get it permission denied.

I have also tried 'adb shell cd /storage...' without any luck.

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: `md "%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%"`

Comment: Hi, I don't have a problem with the date.
The problem is that when I put all commands in a batch file,
It's only execute the first line, (adb shell) and not the cd.

Comment: Is this in Windows or Linux?  Your commands aren't structured for Windows.  Linux doesn't do *.bat files.

Answer (score 1):

The below process worked for me...

First you write all your commands to be executed in adb shell into a file

```
 cd /storage/emulated/legacy/
 mkdir $(date +%d-%m-%Y)_OniFiles
 mv *.oni $(date +%d-%m-%Y)_OniFiles
```

suppose commands.txt
then in the batch file just mention

```
adb shell < C:/path/commands.txt
```

It will surely work..

Answer (score 0):

change `adb shell` to

```
start adb.exe shell
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working.
It's seems like when it open the adb shell it's stop running all other commands in the script.

Comment: in some cases all support will not be successful. In this cases, the user should use better a GUI application, eg. AutoIt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understanding what you need, but it "seems"

```
set "localDate=%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%"
md "c:\%localDate%"

rem Copy to local 
adb pull /storage/emulated/legacy/*.oni "C:\%localDate%_OniFiles"

rem Do remote directory creation and file move
adb shell "mkdir /storage/emulated/legacy/$(date +%%d-%%m-%%Y)_OniFiles"
adb shell "mv /storage/emulated/legacy/*.oni /storage/emulated/legacy/$(date +%%d-%%m-%%Y)_OniFiles"
```

Not tested, and have no way to test.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
My problem is that when I run the batch file I describe, it's only execute adb shell, and not continue with the other commands, like cd /storage/...

Comment: ´adb shell´ opens an `interactive` shell on the remote device. So, it sits waiting for you to give commands. It's necessary to indicate the commands. So `adb shell "command"` executes the command on the device and returns to the calling batch file (so says the documentation, i can't try).

Comment: So the question is how can I run a batch file with the commands?

Comment: have you readed the answer? run in sequence multiple `adb shell "command"`. Or if this is a repeating task, put a shell script in device and use the indicated method to call it from pc.